# Instantiate a new JavaScript object from an existing JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, class, variables

I'm trying to create a series of objects from a JSON object. My current code looks (something) like the below.

```
class Card {
    constructor(mig, sku, title, price, img, link, promo) {
        this.mig = mig;
        this.sku = sku;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.img = img;
        this.link = link;
        this.promo = promo;
    }

    populateHTML {
        return `
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card--title">
                    <h2>${this.title}</h2>
                </div>
                <img src="${this.img}" alt="${this.title}" class="card--img" />
                <a href="${this.link}" target="_blank" class="card--link"><button>Click</button></a>
            </div>
        `;
    }
}

const item1 = new Card('MIG5', 'A577', 'item1', '£2.90','/img/S/GRP/IC/AIG5278523.jpg', '/en/test/item1');
const item2 = new Card('MIG3', 'A32', 'item2', '£23.00', '/img/S/GRP/IC/AIG3622835.jpg', '/en/test/item2');
```

My issue is that when I instantiate a new instance of the class, I have to write out all those parameters within the variable and actually it would be a lot easier to store all of that data within a JSON file or something like that, i.e

```
{
    {
        'mig' : 'MIG5',
        'sku' : 'A577',
        'title' : 'item1',
        'price' : '£2.90',
        'img' : '/img/S/GRP/IC/AIG5278523.jpg',
        'link' : '/en/test/item1'
    },
    {
        'mig' : 'MIG3',
        'sku' : 'A382',
        'title' : 'item2',
        'price' : '£23.00',
        'img' : '/img/S/GRP/IC/AIG3622835.jpg',
        'link' : '/en/test/item2'}
    }
}
```

Is there a way that something like this can be possible rather than having to manually write out the parameters?

I appreciate all the help you're willing to give!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in your constructor like so:

```
constructor({mig, sku, title, price, img, link, promo}) {
    this.mig = mig;
    this.sku = sku;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.img = img;
    this.link = link;
    this.promo = promo;
}
```

and pass an object to your constructor like so:

```
new Card({
    'mig' : 'MIG5',
    'sku' : 'A577',
    'title' : 'item1',
    'price' : '£2.90',
    'img' : '/img/S/GRP/IC/AIG5278523.jpg',
    'link' : '/en/test/item1'
 })
```

or if you have already a json object just pass it as is:

```
new Card(cardData)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I used this in the end and then to get it to work with out CMS used babeljs.io to revert it to es2015. Worked perfectly and I learned something new which I know I'll use again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the JSON data, and connect the value for each key in the object together to create the list of parameters you'd like to use. 
It would look something like this:

```
[
  {
    'mig' : 'MIG5',
    'sku' : 'A577',
    'title' : 'item1',
    'price' : '£2.90',
    'img' : '/img/S/GRP/IC/AIG5278523.jpg',
    'link' : '/en/test/item1'
  },
  {
    'mig' : 'MIG3',
    'sku' : 'A382',
    'title' : 'item2',
    'price' : '£23.00',
    'img' : '/img/S/GRP/IC/AIG3622835.jpg',
    'link' : '/en/test/item2'}

 ].forEach((json, index) => {
   console.log(Object.values(json).join())
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format is not valid, it should look like this:

```
[
 {
        "mig" : "MIG5",
        "sku" : "A577",
        "title" : "item1",
        "price" : "£2.90",
        "img" : "/img/S/GRP/IC/AIG5278523.jpg",
        "link" : "/en/test/item1"
    },
    {
        "mig" : "MIG3",
        "sku" : "A382",
        "title" : "item2",
        "price" : "£23.00",
        "img" : "/img/S/GRP/IC/AIG3622835.jpg",
        "link" : "/en/test/item2"
    }
]
```

If you are using node you can use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to read a JSON file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let JSONfile = fs.readFileSync('./test.json');

let cards = JSON.parse(JSONfile);
```

Then you can use a destructuring assignment in your constructor:

```
class Card {
    constructor({mig, sku, title, price, img, link, promo}) {
        this.mig = mig;
        this.sku = sku;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.img = img;
        this.link = link;
        this.promo = promo;
    }

    populateHTML () {
        return `
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card--title">
                    <h2>${this.title}</h2>
                </div>
                <img src="${this.img}" alt="${this.title}" class="card--img" />
                <a href="${this.link}" target="_blank" class="card--link"><button>Click</button></a>
            </div>
        `;
    }
}
```

Edit: Finally to create your cards:

```
for (let i =0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    let newCard = new Card(cars[i]);
    newCard.populateHTML();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately Node isn't available to us. We're limited by a very restrictive CMS. Also thanks for the tip on formatting JSON.

Comment: If you still have a way to read a file using your CMS, even as a string, you can still use `JSON.parse()` to transform the string into a javascript object/array